# Alter table in multiple databases

Tags: mysql

I have a set of databases and each of them contains a table named 'data'. I would like to add a new column to the table 'data' in all databases. Is it possible to do this with a sql statement? And would it work on MySQL 3.x server?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you must do an "Alter Table" on every table of every database.